# replacement of string from a string by a character

Tags: c, gets, puts

how to code a user defined function that searches and replaces a character occurrences of any of the character contained in another string with a character string.
Cannot used any string variable in the code, has to be a user defined function.
Thanks
This is what i have tried so far
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 
    #include
    #include

```
void s1();
void s2();

int main(void)
{   

    int i=0;


    s1();
    s2();
    printf("c = {'$'} ");

}//main
void s1(){
    int i = 0;
    while (i <= 40){
    printf("%c", (rand() % 25) + 'A');
    i++;
    }
}
void s2(){
    char s2[20];

    printf("\nEnter a string of minimum 2 and maximum 20 characters= ");
    gets(s2);
    puts(s2);
}
```

/*
I just need to make another function that searches s1 and replaces any occurrence of any of the character contained is s2 with a character that can be anything(e.g. '$')

*/

Comment: Yeah, fire up your laptop, use a text editor and start typing. That's how you write a code. Doubts?

Comment: And what you have tried?  At least seach in SO for similar questions. I am sure there are many.

Comment: They do have many but they use the replace function or any other string library function like strlen, etc which i have to avoid using in this program.

Comment: Please format your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
//If I have understood your question then this should be answer
char *replace(char [] a, char b[], int lower, int upper){
  char c[100];
  int j = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < lower; i++){
     c[j] = a[i];
     j++;
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < strlen(b); i++){
     c[j] = b[i];
     j++;
  }
  for(int i = upper; i < strlen(a); i++){
     c[j] = a[i];
     j++;
  }
  c[j] = '\0'

  for(int i = 0; i < strlen(c); i++){
    a[i]= c[i];
  }  
  a[i] = '\0';  
  return a;
}
```

Comment: The "replacement" that you suggest ist just copying. What is `len`? Have semicolons gone out of fashion? And `gets` is not the 21st-century way of reading a line.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I am trying to avoid the string library functions like strlen and without using pointers.